Why did exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS failed?
I am looking at history
what does this command
exec env TERM='dumb' INSIDE_EMACS='30.0.92,tramp:2.7.1.30.1' ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=///01f0dd71d3eb563311f9d396860f0297\#\$ PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh  -i

is supposed to do?
If I go for
echo $INSIDE_EMACS

shows nothing.
Why?

Did the command actually fail? How did you determine that it failed?
